# Why does the if(any number) statement in c++ returns true?

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements

The `if` statement requires a condition to return a value. But, for example, `if(2)` returns true. I don't understand why this happens. What is the condition the `if` statement is taking into account here? Why does it print true?

```
if (9){
    cout<<"true";
}
else
    cout<<"false";
}
```

Comment: Because the C++ specification says that any non-zero value is "true", and only `0` is "false".

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to understand if you consider `if (9)` to be equivalent to `if (9 != 0)`.

Comment: `if (9)` evaluates to truthy, because C++ got the behavior from C.  And C got it from B v4.  And B v4 got it from B v3, which got it from B v2, which got it from B v1.  B v1 got the behavior from BCPL.  BCPL got the behavior from CPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes from C, the ancestor of C++. C doesn't have `true` or `false`. Technically, it does only if you included `stdbool.h`, but it's not built-in like C++. And `stdbool.h` is exist since C99, so there was no way to use `bool` before then. So to check an if statement in C, you'd do the following.

- If 0 -> false
- Everything else(1, 100, -123, ...) -> true

That's how C checks if statements. So, surprisingly, if you put -1 in an if statement, it counts as true. And this is carried over to C++, where you have the same situation you asked about.

But not all programming languages are like this. In `Ruby`, another very famous language, 0 is also treated as true.

Answer (score 4):

The [`if` statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) requires the *expression statement* to be *[contextually convertible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions) to `bool`*.

That is a fancy way of saying that -- in effect -- what happens is this:

```
if (static_cast<bool>(expr)) {
  true_branch();
} else {
  else_branch();
}
```

In your case `expr` is an integer literal, which means that exactly `0` will be casted to `false` while anything else will be casted to `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Any non-zero integer is considered truthy

Answer (score 1):

Goes back to ANSI C, even before C was C++, and still true to this day in ANSI C.

The expressions that evaluate to false are, 0, 0.0, and NULL.  Not sure what year bool was introduced, here is the question that answers that: Stack Overflow questions "Is bool a native C type?"

False was a 0 for many years; if a function returned a T/F value it was of type int.  Don't ask why not unsigned char, this could date to the way CPU registers used to work.

Comment: You have forgotten to mention 0l, 0ll, 0lu, 0llu, 0.0f, 0.0L and so on.:)

Answer (score 1):

This actually comes from C before C++ was invented and before most currently used programming langages (java, C#, javascript...) existed. The people who made C made the decision that 0 meant false and not-zero meant true. I think either java or python pioneered the separation between integers and booleans, not sure which.